# Passar dados de um array para outro

Tags: c, array, struct

Como posso passar alguns dados de um vetor para outro? Eu tô fazendo um exercício e preciso pegar diversos dados de vários alunos em `struct` e colocar num vetor. Depois preciso verificar se foram aprovados ou reprovados e dividir em outros 2 vetores.

Preciso de um `for` pra percorrer o pro vetor principal e verificar as notas, mas como faço para outros outros vetores andarem e irem alocando os dados sem deixar espaços em branco?

```
void leitura (struct medialunos vet[tf], int vet1[tf], int vet2[tf]){
    int i, j; 
    for (i=0;i<tf;i++){
        for (j=0; j<tf;j++){
            printf ("\nEntre com a matricula: ");
            scanf ("%d", &vet[i].matricula);

            printf ("\nEntre com o nome: ");
            fflush (stdin);
            fgets (vet[i].nome,20,stdin);

            printf ("\nEntre com a media final: ");
            scanf ("%lf", &vet[i].mediafinal);

            printf ("\n_____________________________________________\n");

            if (vet[i].mediafinal >= 6){
                vet1[j] = vet[i];

            else 
            vet2[j] = vet[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Defina sua função como: void leitura (struct medialunos vet[], int vet1[], int vet2[], int tf){. Não tem muito sentido este dois comando for, como você quer atribuir a um elemento de um vetor de int um elemento de um vetor de struct medialunos? Para os vetores vet1 e vet2 utilize índices diferentes para cada um deles, inicializados com zero e incrementados a cada novo elemnto adicionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não tem que fazer outro laço para controlar isso, laços são usados para manter repetições (as pessoas não entendem seu uso, por alguma razão acham que tem a ver com variáveis), você só precisa ter uma repetição e já um laço para isto. Precisa ter duas variáveis extras para controlar o andamento do uso de índices em cada *array*. Note que dei melhores nomes e organização no código. Esse `tf` não me agrada, espero que não seja o que estou estou pensando (variável global).

```
void leitura(struct medialunos alunos[tf], int aprovados[tf], int reprovados[tf]) {
    for (int i = 0, aprovado = 0, reprovado = 0; i < tf; i++) {
        printf("\nEntre com a matricula: ");
        scanf("%d", &alunos[i].matricula);
        printf("\nEntre com o nome: ");
        fgets(alunos[i].nome, 20, stdin);
        printf("\nEntre com a media final: ");
        scanf("%lf", &alunos[i].mediafinal);
        printf("\n_____________________________________________\n");
        if (alunos[i].mediafinal >= 6) aprovados[aprovado++] = alunos[i];
        else reprovados[reprovado++] = alunos[i];
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Build3Arrays.c).

Comment: Caro amigo @Maniero eu melhorei a sua resposta em questão de estruturação da escrita, e no operador condicional eu alterei para um operador condicional ternário, espero que goste.. Gostaria de saber também o que você quis dizer com **"espero que não seja o que estou pensando."**, seria bom adicionar com descrição a sua resposta, fora isto te dei pontuação também.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Alguém acertadamente rejeitou a edição. Eu não faria operador condicional neste caso, o que tentou escrever na minha resposta (por isso rejeitaram) a tornaria errada (pelo menos em ponto secundário que você adicionou), e a resposta teria seu estilo de texto e não o meu, não faz sentido você impor o seu estilo no texto de outras pessoa,s espero que não esteja fazendo isto com outros textos. Você pode consertar formatação, gramática, ortografia, typos, organizar algo que esteja bem confuso, mas não pode mudar o conteúdo central q a pessoa escreveu, interpretar o que a pessoa disse

Comment: Espero que ele não tenha usado uma variável global para evitar ter um parâmetro.